# Non-usable buttons any in other FormBorderStyles but None

Tags: c#, winforms

My current problem is, that when I change the **FormBorderStyle** to anything else than **none**, the buttons wont work anymore (I can't press them anymore). I don't know if it has something to do with the transparency key, because the program has to run with a transparent background.

```
public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        panel2.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;
        label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(230, 126, 34);
        try
        {
            t1 = new Thread(
                new ThreadStart(StartListener));
            t1.IsBackground = true;
            t1.Start();
            t2 = new Thread(
                new ThreadStart(send_status));
            t2.IsBackground = true;
            t2.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Fehler",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

I dont't know what the reason cloud be and why it works in **FormBorderStyle none** and not the others. Please if you have any idea, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What Buttons? `FormBorderStyle` has no consequence on Buttons functionality. Post some code that can reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: @Jimi They are normal Winforms-Buttons. The thing is I don't know how you could reproduce it because thats the only code that is maybe responsible for the behavior. I can post the whole code but I think that there is nothing that is responsible for that.

Comment: You understand that you mentioned some kind of problems with Buttons, but there's nothing related to Buttons in your code. If I place some Buttons on a Form (directly on the Form's surface or inside a Panel) and I change the TransparencyKey/BackColor of any/all of those, the Buttons still work, no matter what the the `FormBorderStyle` is. (AKA, *the problem cannot be reproduced*). At least describe a little better your layout, what these buttons do, why you're starting two Threads in a Form's constructor, what these threads are supposed to do and how these are related to the Buttons etc.

Comment: Those threads are a better cue than buttons or FormBorderStyle.  If they call Begin/Invoke() too often then they can easily cause the UI thread to start burning 100% core.  With the side-effect that controls stop responding to the mouse and keyboard.  Diagnose with Task Manager, Processes tab, CPU column.

Comment: @Hans: Interesting as always, but imo doubtful. My post has a simple explantion that covers it all.

Comment: @Jimi: _If I place some Buttons .. inside a Panel) and I change the TransparencyKey/BackColor of any/all of those, the Buttons still work_ Actually they don't. The effect is easily reproduced. I was baffled at first and it took me a while to actually test it ;-)

Comment: @TaW  The Buttons don't work only if a click-through color is use (right, I didn't remember LimeGreen was one of those) and the Buttons BackColor/MouseOverBackColor/MouseDownBackColor are all set to the same color (who does that?). Otherwise they work, simply because you can click them (unless you click on the Text). If you just change the `MouseOverBackColor` to something else, they work anyway. Nothing of this is in the question, though. BTW, the click-through works anyway, border or not (just tested, on 4.7.2).

Comment: Nope. His code, without the threads and with a button on the panel which sit on the form does __exactly__ what he says. It lets me click right through the buttons unless I set the FormBorderStyle.None.

Comment: Hm, I'm sure I have not hallucinated the effect, but it has __changed__ now. The button only works if I enter it fully; the lower 1/3 is unresponsive. But at first it was __all__ dead. Very strange..

Comment: @TaW I'm not sure what you tested. If you put a standard button (gray-gradient colored) on a Form with that TransparecyKey/BackColor, the behaviour the OP described doesn't apply anyway (the Buttons are *solid*). You have to change the BackColor of the Buttons *intentionally* to the same Color (LimeGreen, here) to make them unresponsive (not exactly, just *non-touchable*, unless you click on the Text) or make them `Flat` with no configuration. But the Form's BorderStyle doesn't change the behaviour. At least, I cannot make it to. No matter if Buttons are placed on a Panel or on the Form.

Comment: The setup is: Panel on form, button on panel, colors as in op. At first I was surprised the buttons didn't work at all. Now I am even more surprised to see the the lower third of them doesn't work. And: As you wrote the Text part doesn't work although it obviously should work. So there is a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr:

Unless you need click-through, simply replace

```
panel2.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;
```

by

```
panel2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1,2,3);
this.TransparencyKey = panel2.BackColor;
```

---

This post sounded rather weird, but it seems to be a **click-through** effect. When trying to reproduce I guess what happens is this:

- Your `Buttons` sit **on** the `Panel`
- Your `TransparencyKey` Color is one that allows **click trough**.
- Now you click through the `Panel` and **also all its child controls** including the `Buttons`

Colors are not all created equal. For your `TransparencyKey` you can choose **either** one of the click-through colors **or** some other color.

**Click-through** works, as you found, among others with `Color.LimeGreen` or `Color.Fuchsia`. (I prefer the latter since it is rarer)

Non-click-through colors are, afaik, **non-named** colors like `Color.FromArgb(12, 34, 56)`

What you should do depends on whether you **want** click-through to work.

- If not **pick some random, non-named color**
- If you want the ability to let the user click **through** the `Panel` onto things behind, like the desktop, but still keep the `Buttons` working, you need to pick a workaround.

  - The **simplest** one is to move the `Buttons` off of the `Panel`.
  - **Another one** should be to cut holes into the `Panel` where the controls are by clipping into its `Region`. For this to work the controls need to sit below the panel, though, or else they won't show. This takes a little juggling with the controls' bound rectangles..
  - **Another** is a `Timer` that checks whether the mouse in inside the bounds of a button and then switches the colors.. (Note that you can't use the `Enter` events of the `Buttons` since **they are not working while they are click-through**.)

Both workarounds are tested and work but both do need a little extra code. Maybe you don't need that anyway..?

---

Which leaves only the question: **What is different about** `FormBorderStyle.None`??

Well, since **none** of this whole winforms-click-through business is **documented**, and in fact, general consensus around SO seems to be that it is all based on a *legacy-bug-grown-into-a-feature*, one can but guess and observe that it is what it is. And **with** `FormBorderStyle.None` the click-through feature simply **doesn't** work. (Also undocumented but easily tested.)

---

Since I don't really like the Timer workaround with it constant tweaking of colors, here is how to **prepare** your `Panel` to exclude the `Buttons` (and any other controls on it) by **cutting a hole** in their place and **dropping them** onto the panel's `Parent` below, in your case the `Form`:

```
public static void punchDown(Control ctl)
{
    Control p = ctl.Parent;
    if (p == null) return;  // this will not work without a parent!
    Region r = new Region();
    r.Union(ctl.Bounds);

    foreach (Control c in ctl.Controls)
    {
        r.Exclude(c.Bounds);
        Point pc = c.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
        c.Location = ctl.PointToClient(pc);
        c.Parent = p;
    }
    ctl.Region = r;
}
```

You would call it e.g. in the Form intializaton code: `punchDown(panel2);`